# Extract personal information of a subject from emails using Python, Spacy

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I need to extract personal information of a particular person from the below email

```
Hi Alex,



Please find my personal details below,



Name: Bill Smith

Company: Apple

Insurance number: AB 654321C

Phone: +447677679999

Birth date: 21-11-1990

City: California


Regards,

Bill
```

In the above email I need to find where Bill works, stays, can be contacted at and his date of birth.

I have tried to extract using Python3 and Spacy but unfortunately Spacy cannot identify entities (Apple, California, Bill Smith) in the above email.(may be because the data is in tabular format)

Comment: Have you tried Standford's NER Tagger?

Comment: can you add the code snippet, what you have tried with this data?

Comment: Does these e-mails follow any pattern?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `nltk` (https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html):

```
import nltk
def ie_preprocess(document):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document) [1]
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences] [2]
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return sentences
ie_preprocess('Hi Alex, Please find my personal details below,Name: Bill Smith Company: Apple Insurance number: AB 654321C Phone: +447677679999 Birth date:21-11-1990
City: California Regards,Bill')
```

or nltk with standford ner tagger:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

st = StanfordNERTagger('/usr/share/stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                       '/usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar',
                       encoding='utf-8')
text='Hi Alex, Please find my personal details below,Name: Bill Smith Company: Apple Insurance number: AB 654321C Phone: +447677679999 Birth date:21-11-1990
City: California Regards,Bill'
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print(classified_text)
```

Comment: I guess this will only identify entities. How can we answer the questions like where Bill works, stays, can be contacted at and his date of birth. ?